# My internet connection is not working in my laptop

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection

My internet connection isn't showing in my laptop.

This has happened after my laptop ran out of charge and shut down and then I turned it on later and I started having this problem where there's no connection. My phone is fully connected tho, this problem is unique to my laptop.

In my laptop the airplane button is grayed out and not only is it not connected to any network, there's literally no options showing to connect to one. It just says 'Not Connected - No Connections are available'

Any yes I'm using wifi, and yes I've restarted the laptop five times and restarted the router and I've reset the network. I've checked device manager's show hidden devices and uninstalled one of them but now it disappeared with no way to get it back without internet connection.

I've tried turning off windows defender firewall to see if that's messing with anything. I've changed the wireless adapter power plan to see if that could change anything.

I'm using an rtx 2070 mag 15 and I am running windows 10 home 22h2

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that your WiFi isn’t functional nor is it detected which is the reason you can’t connect to your WiFi access point. Your Bluetooth adapter appears to be disabled.

Comment: It was working a while ago but stopped working after my laptop ran out of charge and then i turned it on and all the problems started happening.

Comment: It’s not functional based on that screenshot. The adapter isn’t even detectable. That suggests a hardware failure.

Comment: Make sure to shut it down fully before trying again. That means selecting "shuitdown" while pressing SHIFT. Or disable Fast Startup and shutdown normally. Wait a few second and turn it on. If the device is still not being detetcted then start troubleshooting hardware. If user accessible you may try re-setting the card.